# Monolog: how to catch all errors and exceptions

Tags: php, monolog

I'm missing something really obvious.

How can I make monolog record all php errors, php user errors, and exceptions?

Before using monolog, I wrote my own functions which I passed to `set_error_handler()`, `register_shutdown_function()` and `set_exception_handler()`. Is there a way of doing this using Monolog's API, or do I have to the following?

1. Write an error handler and exception handler which I pass to PHP's functions above
2. In those handlers, call the appropriate Monolog functions such as `Logger::addError(...)` using a switch statement or similar

Surely there must be a Monolog API that does the above in a single call?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm not able to make Monolog catch fatal errors :(

Comment: @Aerendir, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39080250/287109) if this is still an issue.

Answer (score 3):

From the `ErrorHandler` [class docs](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/ErrorHandler.php):

```
use Monolog\ErrorHandler;
$logger = new Logger('Logger Name');

ErrorHandler::register($logger);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but since it was not yet answered - [ErrorHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/ErrorHandler.php) will do exactly what you're after.

From [The documentation](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/03-utilities.md):

> ErrorHandler: The `Monolog\ErrorHandler` class allows you to easily register a Logger instance as an exception handler, error handler or fatal error handler.