# monolog catch Fatal Error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: exception, symfony4, php-7, monolog

I would like to know how I can make monolog for symfony 4 logging fatal errors:

```
 PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxxx exhausted
```

to the main log handler.

In my application these errors are logged in the PHP error_log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch fatal error in PHP7, with `Throwable` exception. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php

This answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280053/4939326.